# Add new Product type in Magento 2?

Tags: magento-2.1, custom-product-type, product-types.xml

I am trying to add new product type in magento 2 but when i click on product type say Demo Product from the Add Product Select box than it will throw below error.

The requested component ("demo_product") is not found. Before using, you must add the implementation.

**Product_types.xml** code below

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Catalog:etc/product_types.xsd">
<type name="demoproduct" label="Demo Product" modelInstance="Test\Demo\Model\Product\Type\DemoProduct" composite="false" isQty="true" canUseQtyDecimals="false" sortOrder="80">
    <priceModel instance="Test\Demo\Model\Product\Type\Price"/>
    <customAttributes>
        <attribute name="refundable" value="true"/>
        <attribute name="is_real_product" value="false"/>
    </customAttributes>
</type>
```

Here is Modal Instance

```
    namespace Test\Demo\Model\Product\Type;
class DemoProduct extends \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Type\Virtual
{
    const TYPE_GIFTCARD = 'demoproduct';    
}
```

Can you please tell me what is missing?

I am using Magento 2.1.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Kindly update your code so issue can be triggered

Comment: I have updated the code.

Comment: I think your model class should extended from the Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Type\AbstractType. So the code will be like - class DemoProduct extends \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Type\AbstractType {
  
}

Answer (score 2):

I have made like below and is working fine at my end. Please update your code to extend method,

**app/code/Vendorname/Modulename/etc/product_types.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../Catalog/etc/product_types.xsd">
    <type name="giftcard" label="GiftCard" modelInstance="Vendorname\Modulename\Model\Product\Type\Giftcard" indexPriority="25" sortOrder="25">

    </type>
</config>
```

**app/code/Vendorname/Modulename/Model/Product/Type/Giftcard.php**

```
<?php 

namespace Vendorname\Modulename\Model\Product\Type;

class Giftcard extends \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Type\AbstractType
{
    /**
     * Delete data specific for Simple product type
     *
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product
     * @return void
     */
    public function deleteTypeSpecificData(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product)
    {
    }
} ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but can you please tell me something about error The requested component ("demo_product") is not found. Before using, you must add the implementation.

Comment: When you are getting this error?